# What are the common ways to manage database versioning in a .NET/SQL Server environment?

Tags: .net, sql-server, version-control, database-schema

Let's say I create a new column on a table on my local database copy for testing some new functionality, and I want to eventually merge these changes into an internal testing environment and ultimately production level environment? Up until now this has been done manually through scripting out changes. Is there a better way to do this or some tool that can automate the process?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Redgate SQL Compare is what I use to migrate changes from dev to staging to production.  It saves hours of time.

Also from Redgate is SQL Source control which can integrate with your source control system to store the history of changes to your database.

I strongly recommend SQL Compare from Redgate.

Comment: Does it support older versions of .NET like 3.5 or 2.0?

Comment: SQL Compare and SQL Source control work independent of the .NET version.  These are great tools if you are looking to move database changes from dev to test to live.  If you combine the with a source control system like Subversion or Git you will be in good shape for database source control and source control for your .NET programs (either 3.5 or 2.0).

Comment: Here is the link for SQL Compare  http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-compare/

Answer (score 1):

If you are using entity framework you could look at the new migrations feature in the latest version. It will basically check the version of the db you want to deploy to and generate the necessary change scripts for you. Read more here: [EF 4.3 Code-Based Migrations Walkthrough](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2012/02/09/ef-4-3-code-based-migrations-walkthrough.aspx)